# Custom Dojo RichTextEditor Plugin

Tags: plugins, dojo, rich-text-editor

Has anyone out there ever tried to create a plugin for the dojo rich text editor? I am implementing the editor in Dojo version 1.6 and am having a real crap time trying to get my plugins to work. From what I can tell I've done everything correctly, however, my icon in the tooldbar shows up "disabled".

I even went so far as to try [this tutorial](http://dsixe-wpf.blogspot.com/2011/01/adding-custom-toolbar-item-to-dojo-rich.html) but, I get the same thing - a toolbar button that's disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that all buttons are disabled by default, so you'll need to override the updateState function of the plugin to enable the button. To only enable it, only add the function to the plugin. It does not need to do anything. This function will be called everytime the editor's state changes. Then you could check if your button should be enabled/disabled and enable/disable it accordingly.

Comment: yeah... I figured it a while ago... just forgot to answer it... since you are the first to mention it (and you are new)... I'll give you the "check"... but, big ups to those who all answered!

Answer (score 1):

I think you were using an indirect reference to a literal that didn't exist. I added a comment to the blog about this. Thanks for the link to the blog.